# Can't install Galera on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

I'm not very experienxed with Debian/Ubuntu. I follow this guide:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-deb-files/

And this one for adding the required repositories (I don't install MariaDB!!!):
https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
Ubuntu -> 12.04 -> Mirror near to you

My actual steps:
1. fresh install of Ubuntu 12.03.3
2. apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
3. apt-get install openssh-server # remote access for me
4. vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list
5. paste into file

```
# MariaDB 5.5 repository list - created 2013-09-20 12:39 UTC
# http://mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
deb http://mirror2.hs-     esslingen.de/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://mirror2.hs-esslingen.de/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu precise main
```

6. apt-get update
7. apt-get install mariadb-galera-server galera

This fails:

```
....
Selecting previously unselected package galera.
Unpacking galera (from .../galera_23.2.6-precise_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.5.33+maria-1~precise) ...
Setting up mariadb-common (5.5.33+maria-1~precise) ...
(Reading database ... 79533 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mariadb-galera-server-5.5 (from .../mariadb-galera-server-5.5_5.5.32+maria-1~precise_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-galera-server-5.5_5.5.32+maria-1~precise_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/dialog.so', which is also in package libmariadbclient18 5.5.33+maria-1~precise
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-template-perl.
Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (from .../libhtml-template-perl_2.10-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-galera-server.
Unpacking mariadb-galera-server (from .../mariadb-galera-server_5.5.32+maria-1~precise_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-galera-server-5.5_5.5.32+maria-1~precise_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is going wrong? I tried it already with pinning, but I doesn't help either. Is it possible, the repositories of MariaDB are not in clean state? Merely saying **mariadb-galera-server** is in conflict with it very own dependency **libmariadbclient18**

Thank you

Comment: Its possible.  Have you tried to install it by hand?  I would try building it myself https://mariadb.com/kb/en/building-mariadb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently some known installation issues I've also encountered yesterday. The MariaDB guys have "created a page for those who ran into the packaging bugs present in 5.5.33":

[MariaDB 5.5.33 Debian and Ubuntu Installation Issues](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-5533-debian-and-ubuntu-installation-issues/)

You can try changing your sources.list configuration to

```
deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/mariadb-5.5.32/repo/ubuntu precise main
```

and run a `sudo apt-get update` after that. Then simply install the older version until they have fixed everything:

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-galera-server
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like we have to wait for a final fix with the release from galera 5.5.33.